# Problem with kdbg's building on GNOME/Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, kdbg

I have a problem when building KDBG, in particular when running cmake (as shown in README file on the kdbg folder that i downloaded). The error shown is like this one below:

```
mimiview@ubuntu:~/Desktop/kdbg-3.0.1/kdbg$ cmake .
CMake Error at pics/CMakeLists.txt:1 (include):
  include could not find load file:
    ECMInstallIcons

CMake Error at pics/CMakeLists.txt:33 (ecm_install_icons):
  Unknown CMake command "ecm_install_icons".

CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/mimiview/Desktop/kdbg-3.0.1/kdbg/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".`
```

Is there someone who can help me?

Comment: Are you using a stable build? It seems the ECMInstallIcons include ca't be found by pics/CMakeLists.txt, and this also causes the error `Unknown CMake command "ecm_install_icons"`. The cmake_minimum_required message is just a warning for the developers of kdbg.

Comment: i'm using ubuntu 19.10, i found something like kbdg doesn't exist as a package in this version, i tried to do a lot of things, but all of them had something wrong. Now i'm just having a new vm with another distro.

Answer (score 0):

Install the package `extra-cmake-modules`:

```
sudo apt install extra-cmake-modules
```

It should contain the missing file.

Comment: Thanks man i tried, but my version doesn't support some packages that aren't installable